# insert columns of table2 to table1

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to attach one of the column of table2 to table1 and I used inner join and join none of them worked.

In table1 i have the columns a,b,c

In table2 i have the columns a,d

I wanted the column 'd' to be added with respective columns of 'a'. How can i achieve it

output:

| a     | b     |c      | d    |

`select t1.a,t2.b,t2.c from table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 on t1.a=t2.a`
`select t1.a,t2.b,t2.c from table1 t1 RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.a=t2.a`

Comment: Adding sample data will help you get an answer faster.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to get a FULL JOIN , which doesn't exist in mysql, but if you search for mysql FULL JOIN you will find alternatives,

Comment: Does one of the tables contains complete list of existing values for `a` column? or there exists a value from table1 which is not present in table2 and backward a value from table2 which is not present in table1 at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems..

First, your query syntax is incorrect and you arent specifying `t2.d` In your select statement..

Secondly... you probably want a `LET JOIN` because you dont know if the aggregated data has `t2.d` Anything missing `t2.d` would be ignored the way you wrote it.

Not knowing your database... this is what I think will work.

```
SELECT
`t1`.`a`,
`t1`.`b`,
`t1`.`c`,
`t2`.`d`
FROM
    `table1` AS `t1`
LEFT JOIN
    `table2` AS `t2`
        ON `t2`.`a` = `t1`.`a`
```